# Presenting a controller as overCurrentContext

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to present a UIVIewController as overCurrentContext and I am putting the main view background color as black and alpha as 0.8 for that controller. Inside the main View, I have taken another view which leaves a margin of 40 on each side. I don't want that view  to be transparent. But it is also becoming transparent.

Please suggest me how to achieve this.

Comment: Can update your question with code?

Answer (score 2):

Use `[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.8]` and do not set the alpha property directly.

Comment: Hope it will help you out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a container view and then modify `alpha` of the container view rather than main view.
You need to

> add one more subview(container view) to main view with size same as main view and set the background color with desired transparency(alpha=0.8 as in required)
>
> add your sub view(which is having labels, buttons etc.) to mainView but above container view in layer order.